# Stetho: Facebook Debug in Chrome Dev Tool Not Working

Tags: android, facebook, google-chrome, stetho

Trying to debug the Facebook Native Android application in Chrome Dev tools Inspect devices as FB native android app enables the debugging using `Stetho` see this https://code.facebook.com/posts/393927910787513/stetho-a-new-debugging-platform-for-android/

But I am getting the empty screen when i try to debug it. see my screenshot, Does anyone know this issue?

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: After click the "insptect" button, I also get an empty screen not even has the menu "Element..."

Comment: @AllenVork: I think They have not enabled the web inspector for the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't debug applications of other people, because of their settings. Since application is on Release mode, it is disabled to see content. In my case i don't even show that i use Stetho in Release .apk, by doing [this](http://littlerobots.nl/blog/stetho-for-android-debug-builds-only/).

Answer (score -1):

I run into this problem too, I solved it by doing these steps: 
 1. open the Stetho inspector(you may see a blank page)
 2. open "View->Developer->DevTools" 
 3. click on "Application->Service Workers->Offline"
 4. then the Stetho Inspector works.